# Group a number of template matches without a parent element in XSLT 2

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a very unstructured XML document (taken from a Pandoc converted docx to docbook format) which I am trying to clean with XSLT. The format of the xml is like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
                  "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<article>
  <articleinfo>
    <title></title>
  </articleinfo>
<informaltable>
  <tgroup cols="2">
    <colspec align="left" />
    <colspec align="left" />
    <thead>
      <row>
        <entry>
          <emphasis role="strong">How did you assist
          Customer?</emphasis>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <emphasis>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</emphasis>
        </entry>
      </row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
          <emphasis role="strong">What difference did this make for the
          Customer?</emphasis>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <emphasis>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</emphasis>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</informaltable>
<para>
  Staff Member: John Smith
</para>
<informaltable>
  <tgroup cols="2">
    <colspec align="left" />
    <colspec align="left" />
    <thead>
      <row>
        <entry>
          <emphasis role="strong">How did you assist
          Customer?</emphasis>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <emphasis>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</emphasis>
        </entry>
      </row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
          <emphasis role="strong">What difference did this make for the
          Customer?</emphasis>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <emphasis>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</emphasis>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</informaltable>
<para>
  Staff Member: John Smith
</para>
<informaltable>
  <tgroup cols="2">
    <colspec align="left" />
    <colspec align="left" />
    <thead>
      <row>
        <entry>
          <emphasis role="strong">How did you assist
          Customer?</emphasis>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
          <emphasis role="strong">What difference did this make for the
          Customer?</emphasis>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry>
        </entry>
        <entry>
        </entry>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</informaltable>
<para>
  Staff Member: _________________________
</para>
</article>
```

I've successfully trimmed this down with the following XSLT;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="fileDateStamp">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="base-uri(.)" regex="\s*(\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\d)\s*">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>       
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <impactStatements>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </impactStatements>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="informaltable/tgroup/thead/row/entry">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space(.)" regex="\s*How(.*)\s*">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <Assisted>
                    <xsl:value-of select="(.)"/>    
                </Assisted>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="informaltable/tgroup/tbody/row/entry">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space(.)" regex="\s*What(.*)\s*">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <Difference>
                    <xsl:value-of select="(.)"/>
                </Difference>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space(.)" regex="\s*\Staff Member: ([A-Z].*)\s*">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <Staff><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></Staff>
                <DateCreated><xsl:value-of select="$fileDateStamp"/></DateCreated>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But what I am missing is being able to add a  tag around each 'record'. As both `<informaltable>` and `<para>` are both children of `<article>` my most rudimentary XSLT knowledge is completely failing me. I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<impactStatements>
   <Assisted>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Assisted>
   <Difference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Difference>
   <Staff>John Smith</Staff>
   <DateCreated>2014-01-01</DateCreated>
   <Assisted>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Assisted>
   <Difference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Difference>
   <Staff>John Smith</Staff>
   <DateCreated>2014-01-01</DateCreated>
</impactStatements>
```

But I want;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<impactStatements>
    <statement>
        <Assisted>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Assisted>
        <Difference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Difference>
        <Staff>John Smith</Staff>
        <DateCreated>2014-01-01</DateCreated>
    </statement>
    <statement>
        <Assisted>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Assisted>
        <Difference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Difference>
        <Staff>John Smith</Staff>
        <DateCreated>2014-01-01</DateCreated>
    </statement>
</impactStatements>
```

This is a one off job and I am aware that I can change the XML by other means but I am sure I am just lacking some basic knowledge to alter the XSLT I have to do what I want it to. I've tried various different approaches and googled but to no avail. Everything I have tried breaks the format of my resulting XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting and well-asked question! Change the template that matches `/` to

```
<xsl:template match="/article">
    <impactStatements>
    <xsl:for-each select="informaltable">
        <statement>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::*[self::para][1]"/>
        </statement>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </impactStatements>
</xsl:template>
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<impactStatements>
   <statement>
      <Assisted>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Assisted>
      <Difference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Difference>
      <Staff>John Smith</Staff>
      <DateCreated/>
   </statement>
   <statement>
      <Assisted>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Assisted>
      <Difference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Difference>
      <Staff>John Smith</Staff>
      <DateCreated/>
   </statement>
   <statement/>
</impactStatements>
```

Which is almost correct, I think. There is an empty `statement` at the end, because there are 3 `informaltable` elements in the input. How would you like to deal with it?

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I had tried to use XPath but completely failed, this is a good example for me to use. The actual XML file I have has lots of 'empty' `informaltable` elements at the end which I am wanting to filter out but I could of course do this in a second pass.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by adding a template

```
<xsl:template match="article">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="informaltable">
    <statement>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </statement>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

For your sample (and after also adding `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to increase readability) I get the output

```
<impactStatements>
   <statement/>
   <statement>
      <Assisted>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Assisted>
      <Difference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Difference>
      <Staff>John Smith</Staff>
      <DateCreated/>
   </statement>
   <statement>
      <Assisted>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Assisted>
      <Difference>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</Difference>
      <Staff>John Smith</Staff>
      <DateCreated/>
   </statement>
   <statement/>
</impactStatements>
```

I am not sure whether the empty `statement` elements are caused by a lack of sample data or whether you want to exclude some elements from being processed, you need to explain which elements in the input should create a result `statement`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, sorry I didn't make it clear I am actually filtering out empty `informaltable` and `para` elements (which are both linked, and technically not just empty `para` but ones without a name in).  I had tried a for-each-group but managed to get all the `assisted` then all the `difference` rather than together in records! I can remove the empty statements in another pass now that I have some order!